# How to publish pdf using Landscape orientation

Tags: vba

I ve been trying to publish a `.pdf` file from an excel worksheet

```
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\TestFolder\temp.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True , _
    Orientation:=xlLandscape
```

However, the last line does not work the way I expect ?

How can I publish a landscape oriented pdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "Orientation" isn't a parameter for ExportAsFixedFormat (see library reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122%28v=office.14%29.aspx)).

I would recommend first setting the page orientation on the selected sheet using something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
```